# Does a 1 molex --> 1 6-pin pci-e connector supply enough power for a gpu?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

Two questions:

- Can I power a Radeon HD 5830 with 2 [(1 molex to 1 6pin pci-e connectors)](http://www.internetct.co.uk/4pinmolexto6pinpciepoweradaptercable-p-670.html)?
- Can I get and use a 8pin pci-e --> 6pin pci-e connector for a HD5830?

Note: I cannot just use two 6pin pci-e connectors to power the card. They need to be single molex to single 6pin pci-e!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Molex plug should supply 75W; if the card needs 150W or less then only 2 Molex outputs would have to go to the card adapters. More Molex plugs will offer increased stability and allow greater wattages. It just depends on the power needed for the 5830.

Comment: Ah, so this is the reason the PCI-e cables always have two. Since I suppose most people just plug them into two adjacent molex connectors, I guess the power bottleneck would be the actual molex connector, not the wires, right?